# IBM Jazz Team Server: How to retrieve changes from a change set?

Tags: java, rest, changeset, jazz

I use the REST API to retrieve the change set from a project. I get for example the following response:

```
{
  "changes": [
    {
      "kind": 2,
      "item": {
        "uri": "itemOid\/com.ibm.team.filesystem.FileItem\/_2ItWACJKEeGAaaEbbqTtgw",
        "itemId": "_2ItWACJKEeGAaaEbbqTtgw",
        "com.ibm.team.repository.typeName": "com.ibm.team.filesystem.FileItem"
      },
      "before": "_Rx7-BCJaEeG25dOp_iUerQ",
      "after": "_Ngn9BCJeEeG25dOp_iUerQ",
      "internalId": "_NhCzwCJeEeG25dOp_iUerQ"
    },
    {
      "kind": 1,
      "item": {
        "uri": "itemOid\/com.ibm.team.filesystem.FileItem\/_GWB-kCJeEeGAaaEbbqTtgw",
        "itemId": "_GWB-kCJeEeGAaaEbbqTtgw",
        "com.ibm.team.repository.typeName": "com.ibm.team.filesystem.FileItem"
      },
      "before": null,
      "after": "_Ngn9CyJeEeG25dOp_iUerQ",
      "internalId": "_NhCzwSJeEeG25dOp_iUerQ"
    }
  ],
  "comment": "",
  "lastUpdatedDate": "2011-12-09T12:06:52.266Z",
  "active": false,
  "owner": {
    "uri": "itemOid\/com.ibm.team.repository.Contributor\/_hhbosPC1EeCsJbI2ZgPDog",
    "itemId": "_hhbosPC1EeCsJbI2ZgPDog",
    "com.ibm.team.repository.typeName": "com.ibm.team.repository.Contributor"
  },
  "com.ibm.team.repository.typeName": "com.ibm.team.scm.ChangeSet",
  "stateId": "_R7C54SJeEeG25dOp_iUerQ",
  "component": {
    "uri": "itemOid\/com.ibm.team.scm.Component\/_auolkPC9EeCek69P-ztT9w",
    "itemId": "_auolkPC9EeCek69P-ztT9w",
    "com.ibm.team.repository.typeName": "com.ibm.team.scm.Component"
  },
  "contextId": "_Dp6kMdwTEd2jUupDpQV1Rw",
  "predecessor": "_NhCzwiJeEeG25dOp_iUerQ",
  "modified": "2011-12-09T12:06:52.288Z",
  "mergePredecessor": null,
  "uri": "itemOid\/com.ibm.team.scm.ChangeSet\/_Nb_UoCJeEeG25dOp_iUerQ",
  "itemId": "_Nb_UoCJeEeG25dOp_iUerQ",
  "properties": [

  ],
  "modifiedBy": {
    "uri": "itemOid\/com.ibm.team.repository.Contributor\/_hhbosPC1EeCsJbI2ZgPDog",
    "itemId": "_hhbosPC1EeCsJbI2ZgPDog",
    "com.ibm.team.repository.typeName": "com.ibm.team.repository.Contributor"
  },
  "xComponentLink": null,
  "etag": "_R7C54SJeEeG25dOp_iUerQ"
}
```

Now I want to find the source code files as well as the changes. But how can I do it? When i try to send a HTTP Get to the uri in the list changes, then I get a Bad Request 400 error. What can I do?

Comment: hi, did you have any success in finding the source code files changed ? I'm having trouble accessing the file names and authors of changed files within a change set using the java API's.

Comment: Which URI did u use to get this response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rest call you are calling is probably not API - use it at your own risks. Format will most likely change in future.
I assume you found about that rest call while using the Source Control Web UI. You can go to the history view, look at a change, go to an after or before state. This takes you to the state view. Right click on the download link. This is one way to get the URI needed to fetch the content associated to a particular state referenced in a change in a change set. This should get you on the way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found this link by following some URI´s. The entry point i use is /rooservices. Where can I find a refernce what is API and not?

Comment: And the link I get looks like this (https://localhost:9443/ccm/service/com.ibm.team.filesystem.service.internal.rest.IFilesystemContentService/-/_auolkPC9EeCek69P-ztT9w/TestDriver.java?itemId=_2ItWACJKEeGAaaEbbqTtgw&stateId=_Rx7-BCJaEeG25dOp_iUerQ&platformLineDelimiter=CRLF) but I dont know how I should build this URL, because I don´t have the filename.